# delay a function for a quiz in Excel 365

Tags: time, delay, pause

I have made a quiz using Excel 365,
I use xlookup to display the questions and answers,
Problem – I need to delay the answer from appearing for 30-60 seconds before it runs the answer xlookup, giving time to answer the question.
What formula do I need to accomplish this.
Thanks

Have used the formula =IF(TIMEVALUE(NOW())-TIMEVALUE($A$1)>0.000694444, XLOOKUP($B$7,$B$503:$B$803,$D$503:$D$803), " ")
A1 has the =Now() function

Comment: I hid the answer until a relevant answer was provided for all questions. I tested for blanks and responses within valid ranges (data validation).

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(NOW()-A1<TIME(0,0,30),"",IFERROR(XLOOKUP($B$7,$B$503:$B$803,$D$503:$D$803),""))
```

In this formula, NOW()-A1calculates the time elapsed since A1 contains the current time using the NOW function. If the elapsed time is less than 30 seconds, the formula returns an empty string
"". Otherwise, it uses XLOOKUP to display the answer.

Comment: Thanks for that, however it only displays a blank cell, so no good

Comment: @LTB i edited formula try now :)

Comment: Tried it and got #VALUE! sorry still not working